# Undefined reference to `_gfortran_cpu_time_4'

Tags: fortran, rust, ffi

I am trying to call a **Fortran** function from **Rust** but I am getting this error:

> ```
> /src/timer.f:4: undefined reference to `_gfortran_cpu_time_4'
> ```

I searched through the internet but can't find any solution to this. The **Fortran code** is:

```
subroutine timer(ttime)
  double precision ttime
  temp = sngl(ttime)
  call cpu_time(temp)
  ttime = dble(temp) 

  return
end
```

And the **Rust binding** is:

```
use libc::{c_double};

extern "C" {
    pub fn timer_(d: *mut c_double);
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You must link against libgfortran.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663083/linking-fortran-and-c-binaries-using-gcc and adapt to Rust. Not closing as duplicate as Rust is not C++, but it is a duplicate in fact.

Comment: thanks @AlexanderVogt , actually that was the problem. i didn't link it against libgfortran. Now everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters said, you need to [link to `libgfortran`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663083/linking-fortran-and-c-binaries-using-gcc).

Specifically, in the Rust world, you should use (or create) a [`*-sys` package](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#-sys-packages) that details the appropriate linking steps and exposes the base API. Then build higher-level abstractions on top of that.

---

However, I didn't *seem* to need to do any of that:

**timer.f90**

```
subroutine timer(ttime)
  double precision ttime
  temp = sngl(ttime)
  call cpu_time(temp)
  ttime = dble(temp) 

  return
end
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "woah"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["An Devloper <an.devloper@example.com>"]

build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]
libc = "*"
```

**build.rs**

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=timer");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/tmp/woah");
}
```

**src/main.rs**

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_double};

extern "C" {
    pub fn timer_(d: *mut c_double);
}

fn main() {
    let mut value = 0.0;
    unsafe { timer_(&mut value); }
    println!("The value was: {}", value);
}
```

And it's put together via

```
$ gfortran-4.2 -shared -o libtimer.dylib timer.f90
$ cargo run
The value was: 0.0037589999847114086
```

Which seems to indicate that this shared library either doesn't need `libgfortran` or [it's being automatically included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508131/linking-dependencies-of-a-shared-library).

If you create a static library instead (and link to it appropriately via `cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=timer`):

```
$ gfortran-4.2 -c -o timer.o timer.f90
$ ar cr libtimer.a *.o
$ cargo run
note: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__gfortran_cpu_time_4", referenced from:
      _timer_ in libtimer.a(timer.o)
```

In this case, adding `gfortran` allows the code to compile:

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=gfortran");
```

*Disclaimer*: I've never compiled Fortran before, so it's very likely I've done something silly.

Comment: `*` dependencies should generally be avoided, something like `libc = "0.2"` is better.

Comment: @huon I agree with that for a *library*, but in a *binary* it doesn't matter; the `Cargo.lock` will prevent any accidental issues. For a binary, it's better to represent the intent of the programmer in `Cargo.toml` (which in this case is "some libc crate").

Comment: Yes, if you create a shared library in gfortran, the linker should load the dependencies when used I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508131/linking-dependencies-of-a-shared-library

Comment: @Shepmaster, the * dependencies do matter with binaries: it makes running cargo update in future more controlled, as a binary is still tied to the API of its dependencies, e.g. if libc has a reorganisation that moves types/functions around (for this specific code, it probably doesn't matter, but it will presumably be used as part of larger projects). You are right that avoiding `*` is more important for publishing a library, but it shouldn't just be ignored for binaries.

Comment: @huon but if the build fails after `cargo update`, you just `git reset` the changes to `Cargo.lock` and go about your day, update *just* the package you wanted to (`cargo update --package FOO`), or fix your calling code for the new API. There's not really a difference between that and putting the version in and remembering every few weeks / months to edit `Cargo.toml` to check to see if there's an update. It really comes down to preferred workflow for binaries.